# TFS 2015 vNext Gated Check-in builds are "Waiting for an agent to be requested"?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, gated-checkin, vnext

We are trying to use TFS 2015 Gated Builds.  The trigger hooks in correctly, and the build gets created, but it never gets picked up by any agent.  Non-gated builds start fine, and if we manually restart the gated build, that runs fine too.  But the gated build (the important one), just sits there saying "Waiting for an agent to be requested" and "Waiting for an available agent":

[image]

No logs get created in the _diag folder for these builds.

EDIT: Added screncap of agent:

[image]

Comment: What's the result if you change another agent pool for gated check-in?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The message `Waiting for an agent to be requested` usually caused by **TFSJobAgent** service is stopped. But you can build manually it seems not caused by TFSJobAgent and it's weird. There had similar situation for VSTS https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/23812/vsts-build-waiting-for-an-agent-to-be-requested-1.html, but before proven it's bug for TFS, we need to test for more conditions.

Comment: Yes, both services are started. Also, we tried moving to a new pool on the same computer as the main TFS build services but no change in behavior.

Comment: Did you use the same agent or a new created? Please try to use a new created one.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT We used a brand new agent..

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of Agent pool with the agent you are using? And how did you restart the gated build?

Answer (score 0):

Check the table **tbl_BuildAgent** in **TFS project collection** database. Sometimes an agent entry may be causing this issue.