# TFS 2015 : Gated check in are waiting for agent to be requested

Tags: tfs-2015, gated-checkin

The issue is similar to the issue in the below link. [TFS 2015 vNext Gated Check-in builds are "Waiting for an agent to be requested"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126486/tfs-2015-vnext-gated-check-in-builds-are-waiting-for-an-agent-to-be-requested)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126486/tfs-2015-vnext-gated-check-in-builds-are-waiting-for-an-agent-to-be-requested but can't be marked as such.

Comment: I would not have asked this question if I would have found an answer to that question.

Comment: You could have upvoted the other question, added more details to it through comments or asked someone in chat to raise a bounty on it...

Comment: If you know the solution, just answer , or if you want to  close this do as your wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted one of the Agent entry from the table **tbl_BuildAgent** of Project collection database. Now the Gated check in working fine.

Answer (score 2):

tricky problem for me.
After a failed build (TFS seems to have a token problem), the system was halted and any gated checkin didnt work. TFS are waiting for agent to be requested.

My solution was to see the tbl_GatedQueue and deleted the lines in error.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could double check your build definition settings. I've seen this happen when the build definition is in an invalid state, i.e. it was saved without validation errors but some aspect of the configuration is wrong.

You could also create a new build definition with same settings to narrow down the issue.Or restart T[eam Foundation Background Job Agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/architecture/background-job-agent) service  and try again.

To get more info for troubleshooting  please check the log in `\agent_diag` on your build agent machine.

Comment: Created new build definitions . Still got that issue. It was working fine. one fine day my agent stopped working and not moving futher. I have this issue only for Gated checkin. If I unchecked Gated checkin, evrything works fine.

Comment: @JaisonJoy If the stopped agent may cause the issue, did you try to reregister  your build agent? Or just use a new agent or agent pool  like the comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126486/tfs-2015-vnext-gated-check-in-builds-are-waiting-for-an-agent-to-be-requested

Comment: I tried restarting the agent. Deleted the existing one agent and configured the agent again. It is not working.

Comment: @JaisonJoy The issue seems to be related Job Agent service. Take a look at the same issue in GitHub  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19470/vsts-build-waiting-for-an-agent-to-be-requested.html even though it's occured  in VSTS. Detail of the issue please refer this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=13395